# Como fazer um SELECT com Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select

Estou desenvolvendo uma espécie de um QUIZ em C#, e já consegui fazer a parte de INSERIR as perguntas e as resposta no banco, porém estou com dificuldade de trazer a pergunta e as resposta do banco para o quiz.

Tipo um select, pois eu só achei select com entity na forma de lista, e eu preciso fazer um select que ele traga a pergunta e as respostas.

Comment: Como esta seu modelo?

Comment: Cara criei no uma tabela Jogo que contém os campos Pergunta, RespostaUm, RespostaDois, RespostaTres e RespostaCerta...

Comment: Aí instalei o Entity e até consegui inserir no banco com um método do entity, só que não achei nenhum material para fazer o select.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste seu modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas perguntas estão na mesma entidade que as resposta? Se for você precisa utilizar um tipo anônimo:

```
var Resultado = Jogo.Select(x => new {x.Pergunta, x.RespostaUm, x.RespostaDois, x.RespostaTres, x.RespostaCerta});
```

Se elas estiverem em tabelas separadas, você tem que fazer um JOIN com o LINQ:

```
var Resultado = from Pergunta in Jogo
join Resposta in Respostas 
on Pergunta equals Respostas.Pergunta
select new { TextoPergunta = Jogo.Pergunta, TextResposta = Resposta.RespostaUm };
```

Vale sempre ressaltar que todo o LINQ é baseado na linguagem SQL, então não é tão difícil de entender os comando desde que você tenha conhecimento básico de SQL.

Referências:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Valew, funcionou legal aqui.